# Marketing sock puppets

Tags: support, status-completed, spam

Apparently there are a few new sockpuppets that are asking wildly off-topic questions about finding mobile/Facebook developers and answering each other's questions with recommendations for a particular company. There are no links, so I suppose it's been flying under the radar.

Here are the accounts (so far):

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/45785/elijah-dugan
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/45786/mindy-lohman
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/45788/rosario-fitch

Please destroy them with extreme prejudice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If it happens again:

- Go to one of these users profile, then to one of their posts.
- Flag the post, use **it needs ♦ moderator attention/other**, and explain what you think is going on.

This is better than public shaming. You might be wrong, and this case it would be very unfair to expose the user in a public post.

Comment: Fair point, and I agree in general. This was a pretty obvious case, though.